# Facebook active token failure C# HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, httpwebrequest, access-token

I obtain an access_token OK from Facebook, but whenever I try to use it, it fails (bad request).

It looks like the access_token is not being sent to the server correctly. I have used `Server.UrlEncode` to encode it.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

```
string ourAccessToken = "unknown";

//--------------------------------------
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    getAccessToken();
    getMe();
}

// -----------------------
private void getAccessToken()
{
    string result = "unknown";
    try
    {
        // get app access token
        string thisURL = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token";
        thisURL += "?client_id=" + ourClientID;
        thisURL += "&client_secret=" + ourClientSecret;
        thisURL += "&grant_type=client_credentials";
        thisURL += "&redirect_uri=" + Server.UrlEncode(ourSiteRedirectURL);

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create( thisURL);
        request.Method = "GET";
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        HttpStatusCode rc = response.StatusCode;
        if( rc == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            StreamReader Sreader = new StreamReader( response.GetResponseStream());
            result = Sreader.ReadToEnd();
            Sreader.Close();
        }
        response.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    { 
        result = "ERROR : " + exc.ToString();
    }

    Response.Write( "<br>result=[" + result + "]");

    // extract accessToken
    string accessToken = "";
    int equalsAt = result.IndexOf( "=");
    if( equalsAt >= 0 && result.Length > equalsAt) accessToken = (result.Substring( equalsAt + 1)).Trim();

    Response.Write( "<br>accessToken=[" + accessToken + "]");

    ourAccessToken = accessToken;
}

// -----------------------
private void getMe()
{
    string result = "unknown";
    try
    {
        string thisURL = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" + Server.UrlEncode(ourAccessToken);

        Response.Write("<br>thisURL=" + thisURL);

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create( thisURL);
        request.Method = "GET";
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        HttpStatusCode rc = response.StatusCode;
        if( rc == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            StreamReader Sreader = new StreamReader( response.GetResponseStream());
            result = Sreader.ReadToEnd();
            Sreader.Close();
        }
        response.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { 
        Response.Write("<br>getMe Exc: " + ex.Message.ToString() + "<br>");
    }

    Response.Write("<br>getMe result = " + result + "<br><br>");
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you check what `ourAccessToken` _actually_ contains …?

Answer (score 0):

Right settings in App-Dashboard? If you active "Native/Desktop" you can not send API-Calls with this method, see:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens?locale=en_US#apptokens

Comment: Thanks. Native / Desktop is not enabled. Always difficult to know if FB settings are correct - I find the doco voluminous but opaque.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trial and error, I conclude that an App Access Token is not relevant, and that the ClientID and ClientSecret should be used directly. I want my App to generate a set of photographs of registered users. Because the server is making the call, there is no meaning to "me". A set of data can be obtained by preparing a batch process:

```
    string p1  = "access_token=" + Server.UrlEncode(ourClientID + "|" + ourClientSecret);
    string p2  = "&batch=" + 
Server.UrlEncode( " [ { \"method\": \"get\", \"relative_url\": \"" + chrisFBID + "?fields=name,picture.type(square)\" }, " +
                    " { \"method\": \"get\", \"relative_url\": \"" + johnFBID + "?fields=name,picture.type(large)\" }, " +
                    " { \"method\": \"get\", \"relative_url\": \"" + stephFBID + "?fields=name,picture.type(large)\" } ]");

    string responseData = "";
    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://graph.facebook.com/");
        httpRequest.Method = "POST";
        httpRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        byte[] bytedata = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(p1 + p2);
        httpRequest.ContentLength = bytedata.Length;

        Stream requestStream = httpRequest.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(bytedata, 0, bytedata.Length);
        requestStream.Close();

        HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();
        Stream responseStream = httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);

        responseData = reader.ReadToEnd();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { 
        Response.Write(ex.Message.ToString() + "<br>");
    }

    Response.Write("<br>" + responseData + "<br><br>");
```

I also conclude that the FB documentation suffers from the usual fatal flaw of documentation: it has been written by an expert and never tested on a novice user before release.